# Hangfire .NET Core - Get enqueued jobs list

Tags: c#, background-process, asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire

Is there a method in the Hangfire API to get an enqueued job (probably by a Job id or something)?

I have done some research on this, but I could not find anything.

Please help me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have found the answer in the official forum of Hangfire.

Here is the link:
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/checking-for-a-job-state/57/4

According to an official developer of Hangfire, `JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi()` gives you all the details regarding Jobs, Queues and the configured servers too!

It seems that this same API is being used by the Hangfire Dashboard.

:-)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a case where I wanted to see ProcessingJobs, EnqueuedJobs, and AwaitingState jobs for a particular queue.  I never found a great way to do this out of the box, but I did discover a way to create a "set" of jobs in Hangfire.  My solution was to add each job to a set, then later query for all items in the matching set.  When the job reaches a final state, remove the job from the set.

Here's the attribute to create the set:

```
public class ProcessQueueAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IApplyStateFilter
{
    private readonly string _queueName;

    public ProcessQueueAttribute()
        : base() { }

    public ProcessQueueAttribute(string queueName) 
        : this()
    {
        _queueName = queueName;
    }

    public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.OldStateName))
        {
            transaction.AddToSet(_queueName, context.BackgroundJob.Id);
        }
        else if (context.NewState.IsFinal)
        {
            transaction.RemoveFromSet(_queueName, context.BackgroundJob.Id);
        }
    }

    public void OnStateUnapplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction) { }
}
```

You decorate your job this way:

```
[ProcessQueue("queueName")]
public async Task DoSomething() {}
```

Then you can query that set as follows:

```
using (var conn = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection())
{
    var storage = (JobStorageConnection)conn;
    if (storage != null)
    {
        var itemsInSet = storage.GetAllItemsFromSet("queueName");
    }
}
```