# Make Hangfire as Multi-Tenant

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, multi-tenant, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I am trying to create a scheduler using the library Hangfire. Created an ASP.NET Core API project added NuGet packages. (Using SQLServer for storage)

[image]

Added this code to set the server and storage

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddHangfire(config => config.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
    .UseDefaultTypeSerializer()

    .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:HangfireDB"], new SqlServerStorageOptions
    {
        CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
        UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
        DisableGlobalLocks = true,
        SchemaName = "Hangfire",
    }));

    services.AddHangfireServer();
    
    services.AddSingleton<IExecuteSimpleJob, ExecuteSimpleJob>();
}
```

And

```
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IWebHostEnvironment env,
    IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobClient,
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    //.... Removed some lines here to reduce no of lines
    // 

    app.UseHangfireDashboard();

    recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(
        "Execute Simple Job",
        () => serviceProvider.GetService<IExecuteSimpleJob>().Process(),
        "* * * * * ");
}
```

Now, I am trying to write an endpoint (controller) something like **AppIp/ScheduleSampleJob** and the request body looks something like

```json
{
    "TenantID" : "T1",
    "Cron Expression" : "* * * * *"
}
```

I want to run the same job with different schedules for each tenant.

AND Importantly, If I want to see the dashboard with the jobs related to tenant T1 only.

Comment: That should be quite easy. Hangfire doesn't care about tenancy. Just generate a job key unique to that tenant and everything should be good. Example: `{TenantId}_SampleJob`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Thanks for quick reply. I edited my question. What if I want to see only Tenant specific jobs on Dashboard.

Comment: Should also be simple, get all jobs that start with `{TenantId}_`. Of course, that assumes you know the TenantId via authentication or some other mechanism

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that IIS (assuming this site is hosted that way) will suspend the process hosting your website after a certain amount of inactivity. That would include your Hangfire server if this site is its host. If the recurring job absolutely needs to run, you'll want something like a Windows service to host the Hangfire server; the website can still host the dashboard and enqueue jobs

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto **Should also be simple, get all jobs that start with {TenantId}_**. Can you help me with HOW to do it?

Comment: Sure, some searches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54141581/how-to-get-list-of-all-hangfire-jobs-using-jobstorage-in-c | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779394/hangfire-net-core-get-enqueued-jobs-list | https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%23+hangfire+get+jobs+by+key+site%3Astackoverflow.com&ia=web -> you should be able to get an idea from there

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Yes. I should be having Tenant's name through auth info. Unfortunately, I am not able to make out anything through your links. Looks like I need to read more.

Can you confirm again, we are talking about applying filters on Dashboard (view level) ?

Comment: Ah, you're talking about the dashboard, sorry, I didn't see that... I haven't done that, so can't confirm whether it's possible or not. Might be worth looking at the Hangfire docs or its API